# Stop fadin/fadeout event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, event-handling

I have a dive that flashs once on click. If you press the button multiple times it will keep flashing until the click count has been executed. I would like to so then if the user was to click the button multiple times, it would stop flashing after the last click.

Example https://jsfiddle.net/va6njdry/

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `stop` to stop previous animations.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').stop(true, true).fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn();
    //       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/va6njdry/1/

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

**Edit**

Thanks to @AWolff

You can also use `finish`

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').finish().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn();
    //       ^^^^^^^^
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/va6njdry/4/

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/finish/

> Stop the currently-running animation, remove all queued animations, and complete all animations for the matched elements.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use `finish()` too