# FadeIn & FadeOut Conflicting Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to show the paragraph on click to the h1 tag. When the user clicks h1 the paragraphs shows, but it's not working properly when I click h1 the paragraph shows and when I click again it hides, but when I do the same thing again the fade in and fade out effects works at the same time.

Here is my JSFIDDLE example: https://jsfiddle.net/9pLnkqz8/

Here is my HTML:

```
    <h1>REVEAL</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
```

Here is my JQUERY:

```
 (function(){

        $('p').hide();

        var object = {

            revealContent:$('p'),

            showReveal:function(){

                $('p').fadeIn();
                $('h1').on('click', object.hideReveal);

            },

            hideReveal:function(){

                $('p').fadeOut();

            }

        };

        $('h1').on('click', object.showReveal);

    })();
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30842377/2025923 This will help you solve the issue

Comment: @Tushar: If stop() were the only problem that would have helped, but the code here also connects multiple click handlers which conflict.

Comment: I decided your object-oriented code was overkill in my answer, but if you can explain the overall purpose I can show you the equivalent in your object version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a chain of event handlers by connecting click again and again (inside `showReveal`). `fadeToggle()` the state instead and use `stop()` to prevent previous animations from completing first.

```
$(function () {

    $('p').hide();

    $('h1').on('click', function(){
        $('p').stop().fadeToggle();
    });

});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9pLnkqz8/2/

Note, you are also using an IIFE instead of a DOM ready hander in the example so I changed that too as it is unneeded in the new shorter version. `$(function(){` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){`.

Comment: I completely agree with what you say . I deleted my answer I was just using `Toggle()` function

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
  (function(){

        $('p').hide();


        $('h1').on('click', function(){
            $('p').fadeToggle('slow');
        });

    })();
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/9pLnkqz8/3/

Comment: Click your h1 rapidly and you still have one of the original problems.

Answer (score 0):

edit your jquery to just toggle p element

```
(function(){

    $('p').hide();

    var object = {

        revealContent:$('p'),

        toggleReveal:function(){
            if($('p').is(":visible"))
                $('p').fadeOut();
            else
                $('p').fadeIn();                
        }

    };

    $('h1').on('click', object.toggleReveal);

})();
```

**Edit:**
we can make use of Jquery "fadeToggle" function and thanks for TrueBlueAussie we need to call stop to prevent previous animations

```
(function(){
    $('p').hide();
    $('h1').on('click', function(){
         $('p').stop().fadeToggle();
     });
})();
```

Comment: Click the H1 rapidly and you still have one of the original problems.

Comment: I did and it works great.. I can't figure out the problem you claim

Comment: Click faster.... It proceeds to toggle in an out for every click. That was one of the problems reported. You need to call `stop()`

Comment: I click as fast as I can :D. The effect you're speaking about in this case is barely noticeable but - and to be honest - it surely exists. Thank you :)

Comment: If I click 20 times fast I have to wait several seconds while it fades in and out. It should be almost instant (this is a very common problem).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fadeToggle()`

```
$('p').hide();


$('h1').click(function() {
  $('p').stop().fadeToggle()( "slow", function() {
  // Animation complete.
  });
});`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9pLnkqz8/7/

Comment: Click the H1 rapidly and you still have one of the original problems. Use `stop()` before `fadeToggle()`.